# Javascript mock third-party node library on function call

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, sinon

I'm using `sinon` and I want to do something very simple, and I cannot find any solution after a lot of searching.

I have class `MessageService` class looks like this:

```
import sb from "@azure/service-bus";

    export class MessageService {

        async handleNewMessage() {

            //some code ....

            await sb.delay(5000);

           //some code ....
        }

    }
```

I want to test the `handleNewMessage` method , but inside there is call to third party library `sb.delay(5000)` (that actually sleep for 5s)
I want to replace this function and make it **to do nothing**.

In my `messageService.spec.js` file I tried to import it and replace it, but it's not working.

```
import sb from "@azure/service-bus";

describe('message service', () => {

 beforeEach(() => {
        sinon.stub(sb, 'delay').returns(()=>{});
    });

 afterEach(() => {
        sinon.restore();
    });

it("handleNewMessage should work", async () => {

        //This is call to the real sb.delay function
        await messageServiceMock.handleNewMessage();

    });

})
```

Is there any way to replace the original class third party function call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this comment: https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/1711#issuecomment-369220753

> we're not allowed to modify modules that are imported using import. It looks like imports are read-only views on exports.
>
> So, sinon.stub is not able to modify the imported module.

Take a look at `sb.delay` implementation:

```js
export function delay<T>(t: number, value?: T): Promise<T> {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(value), t));
}
//...
export { delay }
```

Here is the solution:

`MessageService.ts`:

```js
import * as sb from "@azure/service-bus";

export class MessageService {
  async handleNewMessage() {
    await sb.delay(5000);
  }
}
```

`MessageService.test.ts`:

```js
import sinon from "sinon";
import proxyquire from "proxyquire";

describe("message service", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });

  it("handleNewMessage should work", async () => {
    const delayStub = sinon.stub().resolves({});
    const { MessageService } = proxyquire("./MessageService.ts", {
      "@azure/service-bus": {
        delay: delayStub,
      },
    });
    const messageServiceMock = new MessageService();
    await messageServiceMock.handleNewMessage();
    sinon.assert.calledWith(delayStub, 5000);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 message service
    ✓ handleNewMessage should work (1343ms)


  1 passing (1s)

------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File                    |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files               |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 MessageService.test.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 MessageService.ts      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
------------------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/mocha-chai-sinon-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/59234255